# Remove and add item to list in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to, in a single DynamoDB operation, remove the last item of a list and insert a new one at the beginning of the same list?

I can only find solutions that involve two operations.

Comment: Why do you want single operation?

Comment: For atomicity, I want to avoid race conditions.